# How to use event trigger library ?

Tags: php, codeigniter, event-handling

trying to understand how to use this Event listener library in codeigniter https://github.com/ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Events

I am trying to send email on Post Submit. My post controller is as below

```
/**
* Posts
*/
class Posts extends MX_Controller
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        # code...
    }

    function post_new()
    {
        // all form validation and submission code

        Events::trigger('add_post', 'system_events', 'string');
    }
}
```

I have created one controller where I will register all system event

```
/**
* System Events
*/
class System_Events extends MX_Controller
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        Events::register('add_post', array($this, 'shoot_email'));
    }


    function shoot_email()
    {
        // all email code here
    }

}
```

But this is not sending any email on post submission. I don't actually understand how to use this event library.

I am also fine if there is any other way to register and trigger events. But not hard coded in to the system but kind of API.

Answer (score 1):

The System_Events is never called from your post controller, try this

```
class System_Events extends MX_Controller{

    function __construct($eventName,$methodName){
        $this->load->library('events');
        Events::register($eventName, array($this, $methodName));
    }


    function shoot_email(){
        // all email code here
        return 'Mail Send';
    }

}
```

Now extend the posts controller from your system_events

```
class Posts extends System_Events{

    function __construct(argument){
        parent::__construct('add_post','shoot_email');//call the parent class constructor    
    }

    function post_new()
    {
        // all form validation and submission code

        Events::trigger('add_post', 'system_events', 'string');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Just to be sure I am using HMVC and `MX_Controller` is from HMVC. So if I will extends the System_Events will `Posts` still work as module?

Comment: `System_Events extends MX_Controller` and  `Posts extends System_Events`, its just multilevel inheritance.

Comment: you will be able to access public and protected methods from both MX_Controller and System_Events from your posts controller